# Music school vs. musical school

Tags: music

I wonder if it is possible to say "musical school" instead of "music school" (with the same meaning 'a school of music'). Recently I have come across several sentences like that:

*The obvious genius of the child had been noticed by the family, and his mother took him to a musical school.

In general, I am a classical  Muscovite, who went to musical school in my childhood,  therefore I dream of buying a piano...*

Thanks.

Comment: Were you studying musicals there?

Comment: No, this is about a usual music school.

Comment: Though the adjective is often the preferred choice (when available) as a premodifier, in some instances, as here, the attributive noun is idiomatic. (For Hogwarts, neither 'magic school' nor 'magical school' sounds right.) This probably often has to do with an inappropriate common sense of the adjective in question (eg magical school; nightly school). In some cases, it probably just wouldn't sound right (magnetic school).

Comment: So it can be said that the adjective "musical" is incorrect here?

Comment: Not incorrect, but do you want your English to sound natural or quirky? [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=music+school%2Cmusical+school&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmusic%20school%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmusical%20school%3B%2Cc0) in my opinion accurately reflect the situation, suggesting that 97+% of people would use 'music school'.

Comment: The difference between a music school and a musical school is the same as that between someone who is a musician and someone who is musical. You can be naturally musical, enjoy music, be good at it, but just keep it as something you like to do sometimes; or you can be a professional musician who performs music for a living. Same with schools. The high school portrayed in _Glee_ is (if I'm not mistaken—I haven't actually seen the show) a normal high school that just has a lot of focus on music; it's a musical school. Jouillard is a music school.

Comment: My double-Hoo daughter thinks T. Jefferson’s use of “Academical Village” to describe [his vision of] UVa is just fine, so he’d probably have gotten away with calling “The” university’s  McIntire Department of Music its “Musical School” with her approval. Neither of them, however, are terms that I’d use in mixed company.

Comment: Not that I’m against slamming Jefferson, mainly because I find UVa’s total idolization of the man, all things considered, quite disturbing; but please note that any & all who have voted to close and/or think this question is better suited for ELL are in no less certain terms calling into question TJ’s command of the language when he used “Academical Village.”  Going against my initial knee-jerk reaction to join the pile of fellow critics of Jefferson by voting to close, I’m actually going to go the other way and vote to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that *music school* is not an adjective followed by a noun. It is two nouns, a compound noun.

- music school
- agriculture school
- carpentry school
- engineering school
- nursing school
- drama school
- masonry school

These are all schools where one goes to learn about, or to become, the noun given in the first position.  They are all “schools **of/for/about** X”, not “schools that **are** X”.  The nursing school is not nursing any grudges nor infants; rather, it is schooling nurses.

That means when you try to say *musical school*, people will assume that *musical* is not an adjective but a noun! They will understand it, at least in writing where stress in not expressed, that you are going to **a school to learn about [*musicals*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_theatre)**, not some school that happens to carry a tune well.

Comment: But ... we say *religious school, medical school,* and *military school*, and those are all adjectives.

Answer (score 1):

The word *musical*  has three slightly different meanings:

1. Having to do with music, as a *musical* instrument
2. Euphonious, as a *musical* tune
3. Skilled or interested in music, as a *musical* poet

The *OED* records that they all entered the written language at about the same time, circa 1420. There's likely not a rule that dictates which nouns take the adjective *musical* and which take the attributive noun *music*. For instance, the Ngram viewer finds few instances of *music talent* as compared to *musical talent* -- the latter favored by over 75:1 --, but the google shows roughly equal hits. Both methods find *music school* preferred over *musical school*. The google finds over 16M hits for the former; 355K, for the latter, although there used to be a  New York institution called the Goodrich Private Musical School. The problem will *musical school* is that it brings to mind a school that can carry a tune instead of a school that can teach one to do so.

(Warning: I haven't accounted for false drops in the google, which will count such things as "the **musical, *School*** of Rock".)